# Spring Cloud Kubernetes vs. Kubernetes API Client

Tags: kubernetes, spring-cloud, kubernetes-apiserver, spring-cloud-kubernetes

I want to run a restapi server, a spring boot app, to kick start other docker containers inside of the same kubernetes cluster. I found these 2 packages:Spring Cloud Kubernetes and Kubernetes API Client. I am confused on what the difference between the two and which one should I use.

Comment: spring-cloud-kubernetes contributor here. Both should work, it really depends on what your desires and functionality is. IF you have more questions you are welcome to ask them on the Github page. In time, we see fabric8 as most probably (no guarantees whatsoever) deprecated, but its a very long road there.

Answer (score 2):

With Spring cloud cal version (2020.x.x), spring cloud Kubernetes comes with two implementations - Fabric8 and Kubernetes Java Client. See [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-kubernetes/docs/current/reference/html/index.html#starters).

NOTE - Prior to spring-cloud cal version spring-cloud-kubernetes used fabric8 impl

Both implementations works fine. While there are many, here is one of the [blog comparing the two](https://itnext.io/difference-between-fabric8-and-official-kubernetes-java-client-3e0a994fd4af). In general Fabric8 seems to have more features.

I am not sure if the Spring community prefers any particular impl. Both projects are active.
Spring example [here](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-kubernetes/tree/main/spring-cloud-kubernetes-examples).

I too have an example using [Frabric8 on github](https://github.com/dhananjay12/spring-microservices-using-spring-kubernetes).